# Periodically press a website button from a new private window

Tags: automation, javascript

I would like to have a button pressed:

- On a homepage using AngularJS and a lot of JavaScript for tokens etc (ng-click, onclick)
- Every n minutes
- From a new private window each
- Preferably in the background

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: `setInterval(document.querySelector('.className').click(),1000);` in the chrome console. Where `.className` is the selector if the thing on the page you want to click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Kantu Web Automation browser](https://kantu.io/kantu-web-automation) is a useful tool for repeating the same tasks again and again in the web browser. It is based on Google Chromium and freeware. The only caveat is that it runs only on Windows.

It uses an intuitive combination screen capture and simulated mouse and keyboard actions. So it is especially useful for automating websites with "a lot of Javascript", where using DOM/xpath-based tools like Selenium is very tricky.

> Every n minutes

What you do with Kantu is to record the task as a series of small screenshots/images and *insert a 60s Wait statement*.  Then press the "Loop" button to start the script.

You can also start Kantu from the [command line](https://kantu.io/docs#cmd), so that it runs in the background. Kantu has an option to remove all cookies with each run, so it is like a private instance in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: sounds promising, i'll look into it

Comment: unfortunately i cannot find the option for deleting cookies

Comment: In the Kantu Editor, use the SET command and then set "DeleteAllCookies" = true. I added a screenshot to my answer. If that does not work, you can even try to manually delete the Kantu Chromium (CEFsharp) browser cache.

Comment: it works well, realy interesting program :D

Comment: Nice to hear, thanks for the feedback! Please also accept my answer so I get my first green check-mark ;)